# populating a text view in an android Fragment from a text file in /res/raw

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am attempting to populate an textview in an android fragment.
I am having no luck at all as the fragment is blank.

I know I am fundamentally missing something. I have read the docs on fragments and I am still confused.

Below is my code for one of the fragments (the others look the same):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ResourcesFragment extends Fragment {


    public ResourcesFragment(){

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resources, container, false);

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resources);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        String entireFile = "";
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place readLine() inside loop
                entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each line to entireFile

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView text = null;
        //text.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to TextView
        //assert text != null;
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(entireFile);
        }

        //return rootView;
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsource"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|top|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the application compiles with no errors**, but the view is blank.
Can some one show me the correct way to do this and help me understand not only where I went wrong, but proceduraly, how to do it right??

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a reference to the `TextView`, you can do it like this `text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtsource);`

Comment: Create reference to textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a bug in your Code. cuz you have forgotten the reference to `TextView` 
so add

`TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSource);`
and then `text.setText("your text!");`

hope work for you:)

Comment: Oh YEAH! Worked like a charm!! Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to find the textview:

```
TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSource);
```